# How to make a tap-blocking overlay in nativescript?

Tags: android, ios, layout, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am creating a custom dialog popup, overlay is fine, except that my taps go through it. Is there a way to make a layout tap-blocking? Like a button does. Can't really listen for all gestures and manually control them, that means I would have to block them on all other layouts that are in the taps way. Don't want to use custom dialog function, because `TIP: By design on iPhone, a modal page appears only in full screen` and I want to minimize the differences between android and ios.

Sample code:

```
    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <StackLayout class="content-wrapper">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout class="custom-dialog">
            <Label text="Loading..." textWrap="true"></Label>
        </StackLayout>

    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: In case you want to block all Layout's events you could set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` - http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view.html#isuserinteractionenabledproperty

Comment: How would I set it? `<StackLayout isUserInteractionEnabledProperty="false">` doesn't work.

Comment: Try just `isUserInteractionEnabled="false"` - without *Property*

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Starwave setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` should block event for the Layout. It would help if you could give more info about you case and for the scenario you need this behavior.

Comment: Ah, it actually works! Don't know what was the case last time I tried, but now `isUserInteractionEnabled="false"` really blocks my gestures. Thanks, Niko! p.s. How do I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: I don't think you can mark it as ANSWER. Click on the up-arrow to the left of the comment. Also if anyone's reading - can I apply this to the entire page - right now the ActionBar is still active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found optimal, from my point of view, solution for this task.

Just need to implement dummy touch handler for overlay layout.

For NativeScript Core implementation will be next (it simple could be ported for NativeScript Angular & Vue):

XML

```
   <GridLayout>

        <StackLayout class="content">
            <Label text="Some content" textWrap="true"></Label>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout class="overlay" touch="onOverlayDummyTouch">
            <Label text="Loading..." textWrap="true"></Label>
        </StackLayout>

    </GridLayout>
```

TypeScript

```
export function onOverlayDummyTouch(args: TouchGestureEventData) {
}
```